# how to get the value from [{"clanid":57}] in php

Tags: arrays, laravel, key

I am using laravel framework and getting a function's return value as-
[{"clanid":57}]

But I am interested in 57 only.
How to et 57 from this .
I think some array method will work.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't seem like a real laravel issue to me. hope this helps.

`$json = '[{"clanid": 57}]';
$val = json_decode($json);
$val[0]->clanid; // here you go`